# How to find area and volume of cross section in sphere

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area, volume, spheres

[image: Circle Diagram]

The circle you see above is the equator of the sphere.

Its radius from the center is $r=3$ and $r^2=x^2+y^2$.

The segment running parallel to the $y$-axis is the diameter of a circular cross section of the solid sphere. Find the area $A(x)$ and volume $V(x)$ of the cross section.

My Answer:

The distance from the cross section to the end of the sphere is $r-y$ and $r=3$ so we have

$$3-y.$$

If $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ then

\begin{align}
y^2 = r^2 - x^2\\
y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\\
y = Sqrt[9 - x^2]\\
\end{align}
The area of a circle is determined by $\pi r^2$ so we can say the area function for a cross section that crosses the $x$-axis is

\begin{align}
A(x) = \pi \sqrt{9 - x^2}^2\\
A(x) = \pi (9 - x^2)\\
\end{align}
To get the volume of the cross section we can integrate from the corner $xy(3-y)$ to $x$.

$$V(x) = \int_{3-y}^{x}\pi (9 - t^2) dt$$

Why it is wrong:

This is not correct.  How can you do this with a general radius of $r$?  Also, consider you have solved for the $A(x)$ in terms of $x$.  If you integrate from something to $x$, you'll get a function of $x$, not a formula just in $r$.

What is the correct way to do this given the reasons I am wrong?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144) is a guide for [how to ask good questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please use both of them.

Comment: A [cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(geometry)) has an area but no volume. If you meant to say [spherical segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment), it is unclear to me what the width of that segment is.

Comment: i've given an edit, at various parts you also used code (i think Mathematica?). Perhaps you could try drawing a sphere and then colouring what you want to find the area/volume of?

Comment: The integral  goes from $x$ to $3$ I mean $V(x) = \int_{x}^{3}\pi (9 - t^2)\, dt$ The surface on the sphere to the right of the cross section is $S(x)=2 \pi  r (r-x)$